# how to compute the difference between the two times

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Can anyone please help me come out the time calculation in this. I need to subtract the two column value which has time data

- `col1` is `aamhr`
- `col2` is `aammin`
- `col3` is `aamcutoffhr`
- `col4` is `cutoffmin`

I want to somehow merge `aamhr` and `aammin` as `aamhr:aammin` and `aamcutoffhr:aamcutoffmin` and I want to subtract `aamhr:aammin-aamcutoffhr:aamcutoffmin`.

For this i have used datetime variables `publishtime`, `cutofftime` and `pubtime`.

- `publishtime` is the concatenation of `aamhr:aammin`.
- `cutofftime` is the concatenation of `aamcutoffhr` and `aamcutoffmin`.
- The difference of both is `pubtime`.

But I am getting errors. I have tried the following code:

```
public Boolean CheckAamTime(string day)
{
    //DRM.Connectdb  obj= new DRM.Connectdb();

    string qry;
    Boolean flag=false;
    DateTime publishtime;
    DateTime cutofftime,pubtime;
    SqlConnection SqlCon= null;
    SqlCon = new SqlConnection(SqlConStr);
    //      
    qry="select jas_L_hour, jas_L_minute,jas_L_cutoffhour,jas_L_cutoffminute  from journalaopschedule where" 
        & "jas_L_journalid in " & "(" & "select jm_L_journalid from journalmaster where jm_T_acronym='jid') and JAS_L_Day"& "='monday' and " & "JAS_IsAAM"& "='1'";
    SqlCon.Open();  
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(qry,SqlCon);
    SqlDataReader SqlRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
    if(SqlRead.HasRows)
    {
        while(SqlRead.Read())
        {
            publishtime=Convert.ToDateTime(SqlRead["jas_L_hour"] );
            publishtime= publishtime & ":" &  Convert.ToDateTime(SqlRead["jas_L_minute"]);
            cutofftime=Convert.ToDateTime(SqlRead["jas_L_cutoffhour"].ToString());
            cutofftime= cutofftime & ":" & Convert.ToDateTime (SqlRead["jas_L_cutoffminute"].ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // sendemail menuscript time has not set
    }

    SqlCon.Close();
    pubtime= publishtime.Subtract(cutofftime);
    //log("timediff" & pubtime.ToString );

    if (pubtime>=DateTime.Today)
    {
        flag=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use TimeSpan and supposing that fields are integer:

```
...
TimeSpan publishtime;
TimeSpan cutofftime, pubtime;
...
if (SqlRead.HasRows)
{
    while (SqlRead.Read())
    {
        publishtime = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(SqlRead["jas_L_hour"]), Convert.ToInt32(SqlRead["jas_L_minute"]), 0);
        cutofftime = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(SqlRead["jas_L_cutoffhour"]), Convert.ToInt32(SqlRead["jas_L_cutoffminute"]), 0);
    }
}
...
pubtime = publishtime - cutofftime;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Out [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)

it can help  you out to calculate difference between 2 times

To Combine 2 Columns you can use like this :

`DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today() + HourColumn + ":" + MinuteColumn, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Example :

```
string startTime = "7:00 AM";
string endTime = "2:00 PM";

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));

Console.WriteLine(duration);`
```

Comment: hi @arjit  thanks for reply but can you also tell how i can concatenate the two times values. for eg. i have hour and min in two columns first in need to combine then and then to compare with other two columns.

Comment: @KhushiSharma can you give me the format for the 2 columns?

Comment: JAS_L_Hour     JAS_L_Minute      
       14                          00
JAS_L_CutoffHour JAS_L_CutoffMinute
 40                          00                             these all are varchar time in db.i need to contenate (jas_L_hour+jas_L_minute)-(jas_l_cutoffhr+jas_L_cutoffminute)

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today() + HourColumn + ":" + MinuteColumn, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: try the above method. This should work, you might have to trim the hour n min column according to your need

Answer (score 0):

Let `diff=(aamhr-aamcutoffhr)*60+aammin-aamcutoffmin`. Then `diffhr=diff/60` and `diffmin=diff%60`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the subtraction operator (-) on two datetimes (literally: date1 - date2) results in a object of type TimeSpan, which contains all you need to compute your datetime differences.

You stated that you were getting many errors, can you be more specific ?